# Firebase hosting and db at the same time

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I used firebase firestore and firebase storage for my android app.Can my website use same database and storage? if yes then how can I do it easily?Thanks.

Comment: create and connect your website from firebase database, and deploy it on firebase hosting

Comment: visit the official website of android to get more information https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 0):

This is of course possible. Official documentation of Firebase contain [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) how to do it.

What more Firestore and Storage are as well Google Cloud Platform products. So you can access your database and storage trough [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com). So it's possible to connect them not only trough Firebase API's but as well trough Google Cloud API's.

I suggest to go trough [Storage Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs) and [Firestore Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs) of GCP where you may find API references, tutorials, best practice etc. really lot of stuff. I am sure that you will be able to find API's for technology that your webapp is using.

I hope this will help!